# WebAuth With RADIUS For Switch Web Portal

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, authentication, authorization

I have a Cisco IE4000 running IOS 15.2. I am trying to login with my RADIUS credentials to the web portal for the switch. Currently the RADIUS is configured for successful login to Console and SSL but the web portal still makes me use the built in admin credentials. AAA looks like this:

```
aaa authentication login default group radius local
aaa authentication enable default group radius enable
aaa authorization auth-proxy default group radius local
aaa authorization console
```

When trying to login to the web page it using the local and not the RADIUS.

Where can I can change this? I can login successfully with RADIUS with console, SSL and telnet. Just not to the web page.

Comment: Have you configured "ip admission name name proxy http"
Reference: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst2960x/software/15-0_2_EX/security/configuration_guide/b_sec_152ex_2960-x_cg/b_sec_152ex_2960-x_cg_chapter_010001.pdf

Comment: @Pompi I have but I am unsure what to use for the name. Will anyname do?

Comment: Ah sorry I was mistaken. Can you have a look if this command is available to you: **ip http authentication aaa login-authentication radius**
Can you may add the output of: **show ip http server status**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is for Catalyst 2960-X Switch IOS 15.2. but should work on IE4000 ([Link](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst2960x/software/15-2_2_e/security/configuration_guide/b_sec_1522e_2960x_cg/b_sec_1522e_2960x_cg_chapter_01000.html)):

```
ip http authentication aaa
```

You can verify your configuration with:

```
show ip http server status
```

At point "http server authentication method:" it should now list "aaa" instead of "local"